# Remove NaN when removing text from a linked input field

Tags: javascript, nan

I've been looking for an answer by looking at other posts but I couldn't find anything directly usable for my script (yet it might also be my ignorance toward JavaScript...)

I'm using this script to transliterate *OnBlur* from a foreign language's script to the Latin alphabet :

```
<script>
function separation() {
    var str = document.getElementById().value;
    var res1 = str.charAt(0);
    var res2 = str.charAt(1);
    var res3 = str.charAt(2);
    document.getElementById().innerHTML = res1+res2+res3;
}    

var syllable_1 = {
'김' : 'Kim ',
'이' : 'Lee ',
'야' : 'Ya',
} 
var syllable_2 = {
'김' : 'gim',
'이' : 'i',
'야' : 'ya',
}

function hangul_to_roman(hangul) {
    return syllable_1[hangul.charAt(0)] + syllable_2[hangul.charAt(1)] + ( hangul.length >= 3 ? "-" + syllable_2[hangul.charAt(2)] : "" );
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="ttt" value="김김이" onBlur="document.getElementById('demo').value = hangul_to_roman(document.getElementById('ttt').value)" style="text-transform: capitalize">
<input type="text" id="demo" readonly>
```

Here you have the same script in Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LGRAq/6/

The first input field contains what's supposed to be transliterated and the second shows that transliteration; however it prints **NaN** when removing what's inside the first input field and I'd like to know how to remove it.

Is there anyone who would know how to proceed ?
Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `hangul.charAt(…)` is not contained in your `syllable` map, the property access will yield `undefined`. Adding two `undefined`s together will make a `NaN`. You can prevent that from showing up by using the empty string as a default value for the lookup:

```
function hangul_to_roman(hangul) {
    return (syllable_1[hangul.charAt(0)] || "")
         + (syllable_2[hangul.charAt(1)] || "")
         + (hangul.length >= 3 ? "-" + (syllable_2[hangul.charAt(2)] || "") : "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you've just helped me resolving two problems in one answer (undefined and NaN results), and you also explained why I had this problem ! Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Bro, We could use this way to remove the NaN from appearing too.

var str = document.getElementById().value;

var res1 = str.charAt(0);

```
var res2 = str.charAt(1);
var res3 = str.charAt(2);
var res4 = res1+res2+res3;
if(!isNaN(res4))
document.getElementById().innerHTML = res4;
```